# Assign value based on output of previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm analyzing the output log of an app with pandas and want to assign each entry into a session. A session is defined as a 60-minute period from the start.

Here's a small example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

> df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': [
        pd.Timestamp(2019, 1, 1, 1, 10),
        pd.Timestamp(2019, 1, 1, 1, 15),
        pd.Timestamp(2019, 1, 1, 1, 20),
        pd.Timestamp(2019, 1, 1, 2, 20),
        pd.Timestamp(2019, 1, 1, 5, 0),
        pd.Timestamp(2019, 1, 1, 5, 15)
    ]
})

> df
                   time
0   2019-01-01 01:10:00
1   2019-01-01 01:15:00
2   2019-01-01 01:20:00
3   2019-01-01 02:20:00
4   2019-01-01 05:00:00
5   2019-01-01 05:15:00
```

For the first row, the `start_time` is equal to `time`. For subsequent rows, if its `time` is within 1hr of the previous row then it's considered to be in the same session. If not, it will start a new session with `start_time = time`. I'm using a loop:

```
df['start_time'] = np.nan

for index in df.index:
    if index == 0:
        start_time = df['time'][index]
    else:
        delta = df['time'][index] - df['time'][index - 1]
        start_time = df['start_time'][index - 1] if delta.total_seconds() <= 3600 else df['time'][index]

    df['start_time'][index] = start_time
```

Output:

```
                   time          start_time
0   2019-01-01 01:10:00 2019-01-01 01:10:00
1   2019-01-01 01:15:00 2019-01-01 01:10:00
2   2019-01-01 01:20:00 2019-01-01 01:10:00
3   2019-01-01 02:20:00 2019-01-01 01:10:00
4   2019-01-01 05:00:00 2019-01-01 05:00:00 # new session
5   2019-01-01 05:15:00 2019-01-01 05:00:00
```

It works but very slowly. Is there a way to vectorize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `diff` with `cumsum` create the group key , then we just using that key get the `first` value of each group

```
s=(df.time.diff()/np.timedelta64(1, 's')).gt(3600).cumsum()
df.groupby(s)['time'].transform('first')
Out[833]: 
0   2019-01-01 01:10:00
1   2019-01-01 01:10:00
2   2019-01-01 01:10:00
3   2019-01-01 01:10:00
4   2019-01-01 05:00:00
5   2019-01-01 05:00:00
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
df['statr_time']=df.groupby(s)['time'].transform('first')
```

Answer (score 1):

I used np where, shift and cumsum to make a session id. Then I used transform and min to get the start time

```
df['session_id'] = np.where((df['time'] - df['time'].shift(1)).astype('timedelta64[m]').fillna(0)>60,1,0).cumsum()
df['start_time'] = df.groupby(['session_id'])['time'].transform(min)

display(df)

    time    session_id  start_time
0   2019-01-01 01:10:00 0   2019-01-01 01:10:00
1   2019-01-01 01:15:00 0   2019-01-01 01:10:00
2   2019-01-01 01:20:00 0   2019-01-01 01:10:00
3   2019-01-01 02:20:00 0   2019-01-01 01:10:00
4   2019-01-01 05:00:00 1   2019-01-01 05:00:00
5   2019-01-01 05:15:00 1   2019-01-01 05:00:00
```

Comment: Try look at you output ...I think you are close but still not answer the question

Comment: I changed my approach slightly... this should work. Sorry about the confusion. I guess now it is similar to your answer...